# Jquery: Selecting specific characters/copy..*real* content not DOM elements

Tags: jquery

I'd like to be able to run a search for the copyright, reg and tm symbols that were pasted in along with copy from something like Word and replace them with the proper html encoding such as ®

So far, I can't find out how to say, Look in the entire document for " ' " and replace it with "&rsquo'"

The only methods that get near only select text in the first element.

Can you search for specific text that is actual content and not id/class?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `.html()` function?

```
$('#offending-element-containing-stuff').html(
    $('#offending-element-containing-stuff').html().replace(/good/g, 'bad')
);
```

This takes all the HTML inside the element with the id `offending-element-containing-stuff`, replaces the characters and writes it back.

May be very slow, though.

If you need to search the whole document, use `$(document)` instead of `$('offending-element-containing-stuff)` (twice).

EDIT: Notice that I replaced the search string by a regular expression with the modifier `/g` to replace **all** occurrences.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be working. I used:
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('document').html(
   $('document').html().replace('&copy;','©') 

  });
 </script>>

Then compared source and generated source via FF web dev toolbar and no cigar. Might be the encoding of these characters aren't recognized. Don't know. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do. Is it a literal `&copy;` into `©`? Because then you need something like `replace(/&amp;copy;/g, '&copy;')`. If that doesn't work, can you post some offending HTML (and I mean the HTML from the Source view)? Also, you must use regular expressions and the `/g` modifier, or else it'll only replace the **first** occurrence! I'll update the post.

Comment: Actually, I need to go from © to &copy;

I had posted a short html file and the script but it never showed up. I think your update though has put me on the right track so thanks!